# PHP Fatal error - Call to undefined method Magento\\Catalog\\Model\\Product\\Type\\Simple::getConfigurableAttributeCollection()

Tags: configurable-product, fatal-error, magento2.2.3

When I add a configurable product in Magento CE 2.2.3, I try to add variations. No problems so far. When I return to the product edit screen I see the variations. When I try to save the product I get the following error (changed user and domain).

Got error

```
PHP message: PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Call to undefined method Magento\\Catalog\\Model\\Product\\Type\\Simple::getConfigurableAttributeCollection() in vendor/magento/module-configurable-product/Helper/Product/Options/Loader.php:52
Stack trace:
#0 vendor/magento/module-configurable-product/Model/Product/ReadHandler.php(48): Magento\\ConfigurableProduct\\Helper\\Product\\Options\\Loader->load(Object(Magento\\Catalog\\Model\\Product\\Interceptor))
#1 vendor/magento/framework/EntityManager/Operation/Read/ReadExtensions.php(48): Magento\\ConfigurableProduct\\Model\\Product\\ReadHandler->execute(Object(Magento\\Catalog\\Model\\Product\\Interceptor), Array)
#2 vendor/magento/framework/EntityManager/Operation/Read.php(112): Magento\\Framework\\EntityManager\\Operation\\Read\\ReadExtensions->execute(Object(Magento\\Catalog\\Model\\Product\\Interce...', 
referer: http://domain.com/admin/catalog/product/edit/id/4670/set/54/type/configurable/store/0/key/3c6931241c19f977a1c6f03ae3207a09140b29c47712291add87d3fcd84df4da/back/edit/
```

Please help.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I had the same problem and when I changed

`$objectManager->get('\Magento\Catalog\Model\Product')->load($productId)`

into

`$objectManager->create('\Magento\Catalog\Model\Product')->load($productId)`

the problem disappeared.

Comment: I have the same issue.Did you edited in this path /root_dir/vendor/magento/module-configurable-product/Helper/Product/Options/Loader.php

Comment: No. Never edit core files!

Comment: Then, where did yoy edit. Did youoverrided this file

Comment: Most probably I've overridden it.

Comment: It works for me.

Answer (score 5):

Check your custom modules or extensions and find if you are using either of the following -:

**Magento\Catalog\Model\Product (in the constructor)**

**$this->_product->load($id)**

or

**$this->_objectManager->get('\Magento\Catalog\Model\Product')->load($id)**

If yes then change it to use **\Magento\Catalog\Api\ProductRepositoryInterface** and load product using **getById($id)** instead. Hope it helps

source: - https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/21663#issuecomment-674535792

Answer (score 1):

Is not recommended edit the core files either magento or any framework. I made one override to the class. I don't know if there is a best way to fix this issue, but for mi works.

di.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <preference for="Magento\ConfigurableProduct\Helper\Product\Options\Loader"
                type="Custom\Module\Helper\Product\Options\Loader"/>
</config>
```

Override:

```
<?php
/**
 * Copyright ©  All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
declare(strict_types=1);

namespace Custom\Module\Helper\Product\Options;

use Magento\Catalog\Api\Data\ProductInterface;
use Magento\ConfigurableProduct\Api\Data\OptionInterface;
use Magento\ConfigurableProduct\Model\Product\Type\Configurable;
use Magento\ConfigurableProduct\Api\Data\OptionValueInterfaceFactory;
use Magento\Framework\Api\ExtensionAttribute\JoinProcessorInterface;

/**
 * Class Loader
 * @package Custom\Module\Helper\Product\Options
 */
class Loader extends \Magento\ConfigurableProduct\Helper\Product\Options\Loader
{
    /**
     * @var OptionValueInterfaceFactory
     */
    private $optionValueFactory;

    /**
     * @var JoinProcessorInterface
     */
    private $extensionAttributesJoinProcessor;

    /**
     * Loader constructor.
     * @param OptionValueInterfaceFactory $optionValueFactory
     * @param JoinProcessorInterface $extensionAttributesJoinProcessor
     */
    public function __construct(
        OptionValueInterfaceFactory $optionValueFactory,
        JoinProcessorInterface $extensionAttributesJoinProcessor
    ) {
        $this->optionValueFactory = $optionValueFactory;
        $this->extensionAttributesJoinProcessor = $extensionAttributesJoinProcessor;
    }

    /**
     * @param ProductInterface $product
     * @return OptionInterface[]
     */
    public function load(ProductInterface $product): array
    {
        $options = [];
        /** @var Configurable $typeInstance */
        $typeInstance = $product->getTypeInstance();
        if ($typeInstance instanceof \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Type\Simple ||
            $typeInstance instanceof \Magento\Bundle\Model\Product\Type) {
            return $options;
        }

        $attributeCollection = $typeInstance->getConfigurableAttributeCollection($product);
        $this->extensionAttributesJoinProcessor->process($attributeCollection);
        foreach ($attributeCollection as $attribute) {
            $values = [];
            $attributeOptions = $attribute->getOptions();
            if (is_array($attributeOptions)) {
                foreach ($attributeOptions as $option) {
                    /** @var \Magento\ConfigurableProduct\Api\Data\OptionValueInterface $value */
                    $value = $this->optionValueFactory->create();
                    $value->setValueIndex($option['value_index']);
                    $values[] = $value;
                }
            }
            $attribute->setValues($values);
            $options[] = $attribute;
        }

        return $options;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I found this error also occurs when trying to access the admin catalog grid..

This query to DB to resets any admin filters tied to your user ID:

```
DELETE FROM ui_bookmark WHERE user_id = <YOUR_USER_ID>;
```

This worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

This is a core issue in Magento 2. Here is the issue url: https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/21663

You can try these two answers in the above issue:

1. https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/21663#issuecomment-477966963
2. https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/21663#issuecomment-501121021